# Creating a script to delete old log files, that allows me to pass directory/age/regex arguments

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a Perl script to delete old log files. One of the key things I want the script to be able to do is allow me to pass arguments for directory, name of the file (such as test.log-*), and age of the file.

Here's what I'm thinking so far, and while I'm sure it's not correct, please give me any feedback that might assist.

I want to run the script along the lines of:

```
script.pl --dir /release/logs --type test.log-* --days 7
```

---

```
#!/usr/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my $file;
my ($dir,$type,$days);
GetOptions( 'dir'   => \$dir,
            'type'  => \$type,
            'days'  => \$days);

foreach my $file (<$dir/$type>){
   if (-M $file < $days) {
       print "\n Deleting log more than '$days' old:".$file;
       unlink $file;
       # or die "\n Failed to remove $file";
   }
}

exit;
```

Comment: Also, it doesn't need regex arguments, wildcards will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using Perl, look into `File::Find`.  Though if you're on a *nix box, you should probably be aware of `find(1)` for tasks this common.

Use:

```
find /release/logs -name test.log-\* -mtime +7 -delete
```

If you want to test it out 1st, leave off the `-delete` flag and it will just print a list of the files it would have otherwise deleted.