# Deleting files over 90 days in Perl

Tags: perl

I am currently trying to delete all files over 90 days old in a directory. The only solution I can think of is more work than I think is necessary. Is there a quick and easy way to do this? If you were working with this code:

```
my $date=POSIX::strftime('%b%Y', localtime);
my $logDir = "/test/dir/"
my $dateDir = "$logDir/$date
#this directory contains files with the form of someName.date
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17978927/936986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), as it keeps the full path information. The important piece for the comparison is `-M $file > 90`. `-M` returns the number of days since the file was last modified.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '.';
my $days = 90;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->maxdepth(1)
                            ->in($dir);

for my $file (@files){
    if (-M $file > 90){
        print "deleting $file\n";
        unlink $file or warn $!;
    }
}
```

Note the `maxdepth()` method says "don't traverse into sub directories". Set that to `0` if you want to look in sub dirs.

Also, if you want to specify a specific name, you can add a `name()` method, which will take regexes and only operate on those files. eg: `name('*.2016*')`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: in my case -M return value with decimal point, eg; 1.32366898148148. how to ensure it just return the whole number, so easily to compare with the conditions? thanks

Comment: @WafieAli What conditions? My check is for greater than 90. Why do you need a whole number? If your check is for 2, your 1.323... will be less than 2. It'll be greater than 1. Perl is magical; you can compare a float against any number (even a string) without issue.

Comment: @stevieb same as in OP. btw, its already solved since I got it on how it works. Just new to perl. self-learning in by hands-on task for current projects. thanks for aid & concerns buddy =)

Comment: The string `*.2016*` is not a valid regex pattern. I assume you wanted to say **wildcard characters**

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly then you want to delete all files older than 90 days in directory `/test/dir`. I don't understand what `my $dateDir = "$logDir/$date` is for, but this one-line solution will do as you ask

```
$ perl -e 'unlink grep { -f and -M >= 90 } glob "/test/dir/*"'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the age of a file in days with the `-M` file test.  From [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

> -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.

The rest is about getting the list of files.

As it seems to need not be recursive here is an example with  [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) + [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

```
use 5.012; # so readdir assigns to $_ in a lone while test
opendir(my $dh, $dateDir) or die "Can't open $dateDir directory: $!";
while (readdir($dh)) {
    my $file = "$dateDir/$_";
    if (-f $file and -M $file > 90) {
        unlink $file or warn "Can't unlink $file: $!";
    }
}
```

The path addition above is needed because `readdir` returns a bare file name, without any path. You can include various tests before actually deleting. (And please *always test code first*.)

In versions prior to Perl 5.12 the bare `readdir` *did not* set `$_`, which is what the `use 5.012` above is about. For these versions we need to do

```
opendir(my $dh, $dateDir) or die "Can't open $dateDir directory: $!";
while (my $file_nopath = readdir($dh)) {
    my $file = "$dateDir/$file_nopath";
    # same as above
}
```

---

We can read the directory in one statement, if we'd rather have the list of all files first

```
my @filenames_relative = readdir($dh);
```

This is because `readdir` returns based on the context it's called in. Since its output here is assigned to an array it is called in the *list context* and it returns the list of all entries in the directory. As the file names are relative to that directory we can also `map` them into full path right away

```
my @files = map { "$dateDir/$_" } readdir($dh);
```

Here the *list context* is imposed on `readdir` by [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), since that function needs a list as input.

Now go `unlink` per your criteria, or filter on that as well to get the ready list

```
my @files_to_delete = 
    grep { -f and -M > 90 } 
    map { "$dateDir/$_" }
    readdir($dh);
```

which can all be absorbed inside `map`

```
my @files_to_delete = map { 
    my $f = "$dateDir/$_"; 
    ( -f $f  and -M $f > 90 ) ? $f : () 
} readdir($dh);
```

since the empty list `()` gets flattened in the return list, effectively vanishing.

---

Another way is using [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';  # for glob() to respect space in filenames

my @files = glob "$dateDir/*";
```

Comment: `$file` will be the name of a file in `$dateDir` but you're treating it like it's in the current directory, which won't work. Either join the path together, or just use `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my function to find the age of a file in Perl:

```
###########################################################################
# In: complete path to filename.
# Out: age in fractional days
sub getfileage
{my($fn)=@_;
my(@a,@b,$i,$j,$procname,$s,$t);

$procname="util2.pl:getfileage";

if (! -e $fn)
    {
    print "$procname ERROR: $fn does not exist\n";
    exit 1;
    }

my $age = -M $fn; # Returns age in days
$age=sprintf("%.2f",$age);

return $age; # getfileage
}
```

Just plug that in, and pass in the filename.
This can also be useful for other users that might stumble on this question.